# What really makes this code bad

Tags: c++, class, c++11, design-patterns

At my company I came across the following 2 code snippets, which I found thoroughly unpleasant at first sight, but in the spirit of offering constructive feedback to the engineer who wrote that, I'm trying to come up with technical arguments why this code is bad:

```
FileTableEntry * FilerManager::GetFileTableEntry(uint32_t i) const {
  return &(GetFileTable()[i]);
}

…
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < container_.size(); ++i) {
   *GetFileTableEntry(i) = FileTableEntry();
   // GetFileTableEntry ultimately accesses a std::vector in FileManager
}
```

My main arguments are :

1. This code is very indirect and misleading, it should not use a
   getter to initiliaze (part of the FileManager), but at least a
   setter: being more direct makes the code easier to understand.
2. The getter completely leaks the internal state of the FileManager, so encapsulation for FileManager means nothing at this point. Even worse, the getter promises to be applicable to const objects, but is merrily used to mutate the internal state of FileManager. Breaking encapsultion is a sure path to making refactorings harder.

Are there other arguments for not writing code like this that I would be missing??

Comment: If `GetFileTable` returns a `vector`, then giving the user a reference to a position in that vector could turn out to be bad if any insertion or deletion happens to the vector (due to resizing). The user just has to be wary; returning an iterator is a better warning to the consumer.

Comment: Technically, there's not much wrong with the code - but yes, it's not exactly "good style" either [assuming it's returning a reference to the entry, and multithreaded execution doesn't allow the vector to grow/shrink and be re-allocated]

Comment: Maybe you could provide a little more code, like the implementation of. `GetFileTable` and how it is linked to container. Anxway, the first thing that comes to my mind is why the file table has to be initialized/reset in a loop at all? Wouldn't the constructor, or `std::fill` be more appropriate? The other question I'd have is why `GetFileTableEntry` returns a pointer instead of a reference.

Comment: Mats - it doesn't rub you the wrong way that a const getter is used to mutate the state of the object?

Comment: @Frank - the const getter just tells you that `FileManager` won't change while executing `GetFileTableEntry`. The declaration clearly states that a pointer to _another_ non-const instance is returned and mutating _that_ is kosher from the language perspective.

Comment: Yes - but since the FileTableEntries are held by the FileManager, in the end, the state of said FileManager ends up being changed...

Comment: How does `GetFileTable()` return a `std::vector<FileTableEntry>&` when called in a `const` context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another argument against this code is that the signature of `GetFileTableEntry` returns a pointer in situations when the object is always present. This calls for a reference, not a pointer:

```
FileTableEntry& FilerManager::GetFileTableEntry(uint32_t i) const {
    return GetFileTable()[i];
}
```

This should address your first point. Your second point can be addressed by making the reference `const`:

```
const FileTableEntry& FilerManager::GetFileTableEntry(uint32_t i) const {
    return GetFileTable()[i];
}
```

This prohibits the callers from modifying the internal state returned by `GetFileTableEntry`.

**Note:** To make the `GetFileTableEntry` function useful, one should add a bounds check of the index passed in to catch errors early.

Comment: At least in debug, `GetFileTableEntry` should display an error message and halt execution/create a dump file if `i` is out of range.